# is it possible to recalculate only a cell or a range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

is it possible to recalculate only a cell or a range in VBA ? What I like to use for a sheet is the following, but how to do it on a cell only ? Or range ?

```
'    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
'    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a calculate method you can call on ranges:

```
Range("A1").Calculate
```

Try it out by putting =Now() in A1 and running Calculate and watch it update the seconds :)
You can for a recalc of all the cells in a sheet by using:

```
Sheets(1).Calculate
```

See also: Microsoft MSDN, [Excel Recalculation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687891.aspx), 16 July 2012.

Comment: This recalculates entire workbook, not specified range :-(

Comment: You need to set the calculation method to manual. If it is automatic then Excel will take the opportunity to calculate every workbook that is open (not just the activeworkbook).

Answer (score 0):

**Calculate: All open workbooks**

```
Application.Calculate
```

**Calculate: A specific worksheet**

```
Worksheets(1).Calculate
```

or

```
Worksheets("sheetname").Calculate
```

**Calculate: A specified row**

```
Worksheets(1).Rows(2).Calculate
```

or

```
Worksheets("sheetname").Range("A1").EntireRow.Calculate
```

**Recalculate in Excel**

Select the cells you would like to recalculate and press:

```
Press F9
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Range("A1").Formula = Range("A1").Formula
```

or

```
Cells(1, 1).Formula = Cells(1, 1).Formula
```

It works for me.