# Different ways to recalculate a cell or a range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The first approach is suggested in [is it possible to recalculate only a cell or a range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342012/is-it-possible-to-recalculate-only-a-cell-or-a-range-in-vba) 's  [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8342067/826203):

```
Range("A1").Calculate
```

The second approach is in [How do you get Excel to refresh data on sheet from within VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154434/how-do-you-get-excel-to-refresh-data-on-sheet-from-within-vba) 's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18621896/826203) :

```
Cells(RowA,ColB).Formula = Cells(RowA,ColB).Formula
```

The third one

```
Range("XXX").Value = Range("XXX").Value
```

seems also work.

Are there any difference among the three?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. .Calculate: Tells Excel to recalculate the formula in the given range.
   I don't think this works for a UDF unless using Application.Volatile
2. .Formula: Resaves the formula in the given range.
   Similar to clicking into the cell and then pressing enter without making changes. Will fail if you have a range greater than one cell.
3. .Value: Overwrites the formula with the value.
   Similar to copy / paste values. Will fail if you have a range greater than one cell.

Comment: Do 2&3 force the recalculate of the Range or the Cell? Is there any difference in the effect ?

Comment: In two or three you can't have a range greater than one cell, so the range and the cell are the same thing. With three you will lose your formula as it will be overwritten with the value (which is not recalculated first).